# BitTorrent Inc role in P2P sharing

Tags: bittorrent, p2p

I have a question in my mind. If possible please clear my doubt.

As per my understanding BitTorrent is a protocol used for P2P sharing. It require client application to transfer the data.

My question is What does BitTorrent Inc do? Are they monitoring all these transmission. If i have a torrent file and i am downloading something then BitTorrent Inc what role play.
If they have created a protocol and i am not using BitTorrent Client, I am using any other client. Are they have servers to create or manage trackers/peers/seeds?

Please advise.

Thanks.

Update :- Why -1? I don't understand.

Comment: Other than creating the protocol, none of these things. They don't run servers/trackers, or monitor transmissions.

Comment: Thanks Geek. I want to do P2P sharing. I will create a client application for P2P with some additional feature. Once i create client application. What other things to be done from my end to make it run. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitTorrent Inc do not monitor or get to see what you are up/downloading, however anybody with a client and the same torrent file (or magnet link, etc) can join the swarm for that torrent and connect to you.

BitTorrent Inc are trying to make their money by selling/embedding their technology within commercial products, becoming partners in media distribution, etc.